# Finding string value associated with max value of record subset in long format

Tags: stata

For non-longitudinal analysis using long-formatted data, when subjects have multiple visits or records, I will typically hunt down a record within each subject using `bysort ID`, and set a temporary variable to hold the integer or real value that I found, and then `egen max()` to find the max value for all records found, then set a final value in record `_n==1 for that subject`.  This is so I can have the values I want from different visits percolate to a single record for each subject.  Each single record per subject will then be used during analysis (but not longitudinal, maybe cross-sectional or regression, ANOVA, etc.)

Let's say I want the highest cholesterol (`ldl`) value for the 3rd year of a trial, where `ldl` is measured quarterly (every 3 months) for all subjects, which can be accomplished using the code below:

```
cap drop ldl3tmp
cap drop ldl3max
cap drop ldl3
bysort id (visitdate): gen ldl3tmp = ldl if trialyear==3
bysort id (visitdate): egen ldl3max = max(ldl3tmp) 
bysort id (visitdate): gen ldl3 = ldl3max if _n==1
```

Suppose there are initials for the lab technician or phlebotomist that did the blood draw. How can I percolate a string value to record _n==1 that's associated with the greatest `ldl` value among the subset of records for the 3rd year of the trial?  String values can't be sorted, so I am guessing the answer might be to eliminate records for which `ldl` is not the greatest value in year 3, then the string will be in that record?

In this case, how can I find out what _n is for the maximum value?  If I know that, I could use

```
bysort id (visitdate): drop if _n!=6 //if _n==6 has the max value of ldl
```

Comment: String values can be `sort`ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to find the record number associated with the greatest `ldl` value within 4 quarterly `ldl` values in year 3 of a trial.  The result is a variable called `recmax`, which will only be filled in for the specific record where the greatest value was found (among all records for each subject).

```
cap drop tmpldl3
cap drop maxldl3
cap drop recmax
cap drop visitdate
gen long visitdate = date(dateofvisit, "MDY") //You have to convert date ("MM/DD/YYYY") to a long integer format - based on #days since Jan 1, 1960
bysort id (visitdate): gen tmpldl3 = ldl if trialyear ==3  
bysort id (visitdate): egen maxldl3 = max(tmpldl3) 
bysort id (visitdate): gen recmax = _n if tmpldl3==maxldl3 & tmpldl3!=. & maxldl3!=.
```

You can then analyze all the other data (such as string data) in that record cross-sectionally (ANOVA, correlation, regression) by specifying `if recmax!=.` in the trailing if statement for any analysis command. If you are careful, you could also `drop` all other records with extraneous `ldl` values not of interest by using the command `drop if recmax!=.` providing you realize you dropped data and if you save, save to a filename with "_reduced" or "_dropped" in it.

Comment: Setting aside the resolution used for the variable mentioned (not stated), there is a general pitfall to flag. To compare a maximum with the original, it is sometimes important to ensure that the same storage type is used. So if the original is `double` use a `double` to hold the maximum too.

Comment: Thanks Nick, that's a good point. I did notice first that if `tmpldl3!=. & maxldl3!=.` is not added to the if statement, you get a 1,2,3,4,... for every within-subject record, since Stata has an integer issue with missing.   I recall missing can be interpreted as an infinity integer.  Thus finding the record with `tmpldl3==maxldl3` is true if both `tmpldl3` and `maxldl3` are missing -- hence the need to enforce that  `tmpldl3` and `maxldl3` cannot be missing.

Comment: It works out that I need to percolate string values from other within-subject records/variables to record _n==1.   So is there a way to `copy` a string value to all within-subject records so that I can eventually move them to record _n==1? In other words, I have to do a lot of heavy lifting to move a lot of string information from multiple variables into a single within-subject record.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow what you're asking in comments. Suggest you make that a question with a self-contained data example, etc.